# Use OpenMP with Xeon Phi using k1om-mpss-linux-gcc compiler

Tags: openmp, xeon-phi

I am trying to use OpenMP with k1om-mpss-linux-gcc compiler for Xeon Phi cards. I tried a simple example, but I got this error:

```
fatal error: omp.h: No such file or directory
```

How can I solve this issue?? Have anybody experienced with k1om-mpss-linux-gcc compiler?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure how standard that is, bit on my own MIC node, I have MPSS version 3.6 installed, which comes with GCC 5.1.1.

And calling:

```
/opt/mpss/3.6/sysroots/x86_64-mpsssdk-linux/usr/bin/k1om-mpss-linux/k1om-mpss-linux-gcc -v
```

gives amongst many other things:

```
Configured with: [...] --disable-libgomp [...]
```

So it looks like OpenMP isn't supported by the version of GCC that comes with MPSS. That said, maybe you can compile it yourself with this support enabled (I have no idea how simple that would be).